# R: How to make sequence (1,1,1,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,7,7,8)

Tags: r

Title says it all: how would I code such a repeating sequence where the base repeat unit is : a vector c(1,1,1,2) - repeated 4 times, but incrementing the values in the vector by 2 each time?

I've tried a variety of rep,times,each,seq and can't get the wanted result out..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
c(1,1,1,2) + rep(seq(0, 6, 2), each = 4)
# [1] 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 4 5 5 5 6 7 7 7 8
```

Answer (score 4):

The `rep` function allows for a vector of the same length as `x` to be used in the `times` argument. We can extend the desired pattern with the super secret `rep_len`.

```
rep(1:8, rep_len(c(3, 1), 8))
#[1] 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 4 5 5 5 6 7 7 7 8
```

Comment: There is nothing secret about `rep_len()`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I get it right but what's wrong with something as simple as that:

```
rep<-c(1,1,1,2)
step<-2
vec<-c(rep,step+rep,2*step+rep,3*step+rep)
```

Answer (score 1):

I accepted luke as it is the easiest for me to understand (and closest to what I was already trying, but failing with!)

I have used this final form:

```
> c(1,1,1,2)+rep(c(0,2,4,6),each=4)
[1] 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 4 5 5 5 6 7 7 7 8
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

`pattern <- rep(c(3, 1), len = 50)
unlist(lapply(1:8, function(x) rep(x, pattern[x])))
[1] 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 4 5 5 5 6 7 7 7 8`

This lets you just adjust the length of the pattern under `rep(len = X)` and removes any usage of addition, which some of the other answers show.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
input <- c(1,1,1,2)
n <- 4
increment <- 2
sort(rep.int(seq.int(from = 0, by = increment, length.out = n), length(input))) + input

[1] 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 4 5 5 5 6 7 7 7 8
```